# A single request appears to have come from all the browsers? Should I be worried?

Tags: security, user-agent

I was looking over my site access logs when I noticed a request with the following user agent string:

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT
>   5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026
>   Firefox/3.6.12\",\"Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl-PL;
>   rv:1.8.1.24pre) Gecko/20100228
>   K-Meleon/1.5.4\",\"Mozilla/5.0 (X11;
>   U; Linux x86_64; en-US)
>   AppleWebKit/540.0 (KHTML,like Gecko)
>   Chrome/9.1.0.0
>   Safari/540.0\",\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;
>   U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US)
>   AppleWebKit/532.5 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Comodo_Dragon/4.1.1.11
>   Chrome/4.1.249.1042
>   Safari/532.5\",\"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U;
>   Linux i686 (x86_64); en-US;
>   rv:1.9.0.16) Gecko/2009122206
>   Firefox/3.0.16
>   Flock/2.5.6\",\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;
>   U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US)
>   AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Maxthon/3.0.8.2
>   Safari/533.1\",\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;
>   U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US;
>   rv:1.8.1.8pre) Gecko/20070928
>   Firefox/2.0.0.7
>   Navigator/9.0RC1\",\"Opera/9.99
>   (Windows NT 5.1; U; pl)
>   Presto/9.9.9\",\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;
>   U; Windows NT 6.1; zh-HK)
>   AppleWebKit/533.18.1 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Version/5.0.2
>   Safari/533.18.5\",\"Seamonkey-1.1.13-1(X11;
>   U; GNU Fedora fc 10)
>   Gecko/20081112\",\"Mozilla/5.0
>   (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1;
>   Win64; x64; Trident/5.0; .NET CLR
>   2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC
>   6.0; Zune 4.0; Tablet PC 2.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C;
>   .NET4.0E)\",\"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET4.0C;
>   .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)"

The request appears to have originated from 91.121.153.210 - which appears to be owned by these guys: http://www.medialta.eu/accueil.html

I find this rather impressive - a request from *'all'* user-agents.

There's actually quite a few of these requests over at least the few days - so it naturally piqued my interested.

Searching Google simply seems to produce a very long list of websites which make their Apache access logs publicly available...

Is this some weird indication that we're being targeted? And by who?

Answer (score 3):

You failed to share the ip address of the request - so its a bit more difficult to answer the who - but a good idea of why could be a simple scan to check and see if the website is working with all browsers.

This is standard for many developers when they make a change - 
services like www.BrowserShots.org generally show up this way.

Comment: oops - have added the IP address.